# How to find all the entire functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find all the  entire  functions such that  $|f(z)|\le \frac{ |z|^{10}}{\log |z|}$ for $|z| >1 $?

I was thinking about Cauchy estimates formula

$ |f^{n} (z) |\le \frac{M. n!}{r^n}$

$|f^{10}(z)| \le \frac{|z|}{ (\log |z|)^{\frac{1}{10}}}$

Im confused  that how can i find the entire function

Comment: Hint: Liouville's Theorem

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula applied to $z=0$ and $\partial D(0,r)$ shows that $f$ is a polynomial of $\leq9$ degrees (we let $r\rightarrow\infty$. But I'm not sure if there is a nice description of the set of all such polynomials.